# Configure django server in httpd with reverse proxy

Tags: django, apache, django-1.8

I have an application running on django server 1.8x which I need to configure in apache httpd server 2.2.x using reverse proxy method.  I tried making changes in sites-available/000-default.conf, but it didn't worked. It tried to navigate but it got timed out.  My httpd server is running on port 80 and django server on port 8000.  Since I am new to django and httpd, so needs assistance.

Comment: Can you paste, what you did in conf as of now for proxy bypass

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /abc http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /abc http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>

Then we tried accessing it through http://<ip>/abc. But it is redirecting to some other IP.

Comment: I trust that you have checked the config file properly and there is no other redirection. The best way to check it, would be search for the IP address(which is getting redirected) in all config files.

Comment: I am unable to find the redirecting ip in any of the files. Can you please suggest any other approach.  I am using Ubuntu system 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

# And inside the <VirtualHost *:80> add below
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

And make sure you enabled the mod_poxy and then restart httpd.